# how to add checkbox to the dxDataGrid grouped row

Tags: devextreme

There are **grouped rows** in the dxdatagrid `table.checkbox` should be there in front of each grouped row.

I have already tried `using .dxCheckbox()` and it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
groupCellTemplate: function (container, options) {
                    let value = 1;
                    for (const item of options.data.items) {
                        if (item.isPermission === "0") {
                            value = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return $("<div class='row' />").append(
                        $("<b class='col-sm-9' />").text(options.displayValue),
                        $("<div class='col-sm-2 text-center pl-0' />").append(
                            $("<div>").dxCheckBox({
                                value: value,
                                onValueChanged: function (data) {
                                    if (data.value) {
                                        for (const key in options.data.items) {
                                            options.data.items[key].isPermission = "1";
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        for (const key in options.data.items) {
                                            options.data.items[key].isPermission = "0";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    dx_gridGroup.option("dataSource", permissions);
                                },
                            })
                        )
                    );
                }
```

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? What are the key elements that solve the problem? Answers are more useful when accompanied by an explanation.

Comment: I set filed column checkbox is isPermission after foreach checkbox if checked then update datasource